# Не удалось включить ограничения

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Добрый день, не могу понять как отключить необходимость определения ключей и значений в запросе к T-SQL , делаю запрос к серверу

```
    SELECT
    Dates,
    Name,
    REPLACE(SpecialistName, 'ttt-', ''),
    WorkerName,
    PaymentTypeName,
    CASE InputPlace
        WHEN 'D' THEN 'Z'
        WHEN 'K' THEN 'Z'
        WHEN 'W' THEN 'Z'
        ELSE 'X'
    END,
    COUNT(*),
    SUM(CASE WHEN Code_Ref IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Обслужено]
FROM Cards
JOIN Xment ON XmentID = XmentID_Ref
JOIN Worker ON WorkerID = MtorID_Ref
LEFT JOIN Specialist ON SpecialistID = SpecialistID_Ref
JOIN PaymentType ON PaymentTypeID = PaymentTypeID_Ref
WHERE Dates BETWEEN '20150401' AND '20150414' AND HelpPlaceID_Ref = 1
GROUP BY Dates, Name, SpecficName, WorkerName, PaymentTypeName, InputPlace
ORDER BY Dates, Name, SpecficName, WorkerName, PaymentTypeName, InputPlace
```

а возвращает он мне

> Не удалось включить ограничения. По меньшей мере одна строка содержит значение, нарушающее ограничения по отсутствию пустых значений, уникальности или внешним ключам.

в Management Studio всё работает прекрасно, а вот в программе выдает ошибку, часть кода программы

```
InstallConnect.Open();
var StatConnect = InstallConnect.State;
if (StatConnect.ToString() == "Open")
{
    ValueStatusSQLC.StatusConnect = true;
    if (ValueStatusSQLC.ExecuteCommand)
    {
        ValueDataConnect.SendCommand.Connection = InstallConnect;
        ValueDataConnect.SendCommand.CommandText = ValueDataConnect.CodeQuery.ToString();
        SqlDataReader ResultQuery = ValueDataConnect.SendCommand.ExecuteReader();
        Thread CancelTransaction = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CancelQuery));
        CancelTransaction.Start();
        CancelTransaction.Join();
        int CheckColums = ResultQuery.FieldCount;
        ValueDataConnect.TablesQuery.Load(ResultQuery);
        foreach (string Line in ListAnwers)
        {
            ComponentForm1.Invoke(new Action(() => ComponentForm1.richTextBox2.AppendText("SQL Server " + NameServer + " > " + Line + '\n')));
        }
        InstallConnect.Close();
        if (CheckColums != 0)
        {
            if (!ValueStatusSQLC.OpenOutputResultSql)
            {
                OutputResultSql StartForm = new OutputResultSql();
                ComponentForm1.Invoke(new Action(() => StartForm.ShowDialog()));
            }
            else if (ValueStatusSQLC.OpenOutputResultSql)
            {
                OutputResultSql StartUpdate = new OutputResultSql();
            }
        }
        else if (CheckColums == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ResultQuery.ToString(), "Результат соединения", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN Code_Ref IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Comment: Недопустимое приведение "DateTime" к "Double".
WHERE Dates BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-14' AND HelpPlaceID_Ref = 1

Comment: '20150401' - независимый от настроек формат. но ошибка у вас не относится к SQL , смотрите в вашем коде, может где-то передача параметров неправильная

Comment: да.......... на сервере этот код работает прекрасно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Не удалось включить ограничения" - это не ошибка SQL. Такую ошибку бросает класс DataSet при загрузке в него неконсистентных данных. Ловите ошибку в отладчике и смотрите значение результат вызова `dt.GetErrors()` у того датасета, который бросил ошибку - в нем будут подробности.

Comment: Почему DataGridView не может привести значения с DateTime к Double, да и зачем он его приводит, в коде этого нет. То есть сейчас основная проблема с типами передаваемыми из DataTable в DataGridView

Answer (score 3):

Если кому ни будь пригодится. Такая ошибка может возникать, если длина поля меньше, чем в таблице.

Answer (score 1):

Когда создается представление в SQL Server и затем строится `DataSet` в студии, в конструкторе выставляется длина поля. После этого изменяется (например) одно поле в представлении, которое выводит уже не 2-значную строку, а 50-значную. 
Но в конструкторе будет стоять максимальная длина 2 символа на это поле и при запуске выдаст ошибку "Не удалось включить ограничения. По меньшей мере одна строка содержит значение, нарушающее ограничения по отсутствию пустых значений, уникальности или внешним ключам."

Для исправления заходим в конструктор `DataSet`, выделяем нужное поле в таблице и изменяем его максимальную длину.

И второй момент бывает - когда делается запрос, в `DataSet` автоматом ставится отметка о уникальном ключе таблице, хотя он иногда не нужен. Убираем в таблице `DataSet` этот ключ и ошибка исчезает.

Answer (score 1):

В функции формы:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

есть строки вида:

```
// TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "uchDataSet.Категория_товара". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
    this.категория_товараTableAdapter.Fill(this.uchDataSet.Категория_товара);

// TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "uchDataSet.Товары". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
    this.товарыTableAdapter.Fill(this.uchDataSet.Товары);
```

Они формируются автоматом. У меня первой шла строка загрузки `uchDataSet.Товары` - FK, а лишь потом `uchDataSet.Категория_товара` - PK. То есть, FK ссылался в никуда.

Поменял их местами, ошибка устранилась.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в DataSet, по умолчанию Maxlength строки 64 символа, если зарос возращает строку длинее, то такая ошибка выходит, поэтому и в Managmet Studio работает а в Visual Studio - нет

Answer (score 0):

Это случается, когда Вы изменили хранимую процедуру или представление (например, изменилось количество возвращвемых полей или сами поля), но не поменяли соответствующий адаптер в проекте. Решение - пересоздать адаптер.